# WTForms RadioField default values

Tags: python, wtforms

I'm generating a html form with wtforms like this:

```
<div class="control-group">
    {% for subfield in form.time_offset %}
    <label class="radio">
        {{ subfield }}
        {{ subfield.label }}
    </label>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

My form class is like this:

```
class SN4639(Form):
    time_offset = RadioField(u'Label', choices=[
        ('2', u'Check when Daylight saving has begun, UTC+02:00'),
        ('1', u'Check when Daylight saving has stopped, UTC+01:00')],
        default=2, validators=[Required()])
```

When I now open the edit form, I get via SQL the value 1 or 2 - how can I preset the specifiy radiobutton?

Comment: If you want to set default at forms for which reasons are you want to do that in html? Do you want two default values?

Comment: At the creation form, I set defaults, as you can see, in the class. But now I'm creating a edit form and there it should be pre-selected. e.g. "male / female" and when I got the value 'm' from the db, male should be selected... How can I do this?

Comment: default=yourObjectFromDB.sex ????

Comment: Hi, sorry, maybe I'm to new or dump... and don't get it. Do you set this in the class or in the template? However, looks like I'll keep trying this weekend.

Comment: lel, I understand you set class as usually but attache _ at the end that's because "class" is a reserved word. So you can set class in templates like this class_="someclass"

Answer (score 12):

default=2 needs to be of type string, not int:

```
class SN4639(Form):
    time_offset = RadioField(u'Label', choices=[
        ('2', u'Check when Daylight saving has begun, UTC+02:00'),
        ('1', u'Check when Daylight saving has stopped, UTC+01:00')],
        default='2', validators=[Required()])
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question properly, you want to have the form render with a pre-selected choice (rather than returning a default choice if no value is submitted to the form)...

What you can do is construct the form while setting the pre-selected value:

```
myform = SN4639(time_offset='2')
```

And then pass `myform` off to your template to be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

My friend,

You need to fill in the .data field with the data that is in the database after instantiating the form. See that example:

```
my_instance = SN4639()
my_db_id = get_id_on_my_db()  # fill the variable with the database id

my_instance.time_offset.data = my_db_id  # here's the cat jump
```

Now, when you use my_instance.time_offset () in your HTML, the correct radio will be selected

**IMPORTANTE NOTE:**

If your id is an integer, you must add the parameter coerce=int in RadioField. See that example:

```
time_offset = RadioField(u'Label', choices=[
    (2, u'Check when Daylight saving has begun, UTC+02:00'),
    (1, u'Check when Daylight saving has stopped, UTC+01:00')],
    coerce=int,
    default=2, validators=[Required()])
```

Comment: almost 1 year later i am feeling sad because i replied like this.

Answer (score -1):

`Form.__init__` takes a keyword argument `obj=` which will populate the form from the given object if no formdata or other defaults are provided.  Pass the result from the database to that and it should work.